# Проверить систему на пользовательскую активность

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

Нужно проверить систему на активность, то есть проверить какое время назад был произведен сдвиг мышью или когда была использована клавиатура. Не нашел данного ответа на просторах русского и английского интернета. Были пару вариантов, но они показывали только время с начала запуска системы.

Comment: Трояна писать не надо вам.

Comment: Да ладно вам, какой тут может быть троян? Просто интересуюсь. Может подскажите ответ то?

Comment: Какую систему собираетесь проверять? В C++ нет встроенных средств для таких проверок.

Comment: Автозагрузка + неактивность системы + инжект? Любой трой тут может быть и набор техник стандартный.

Comment: Нужно проверять windows

Comment: Зачем вам это? есть событие "перехода" в спящий/ждущий режим. Есть решение, позволяющее запретить переходить в спящий/ждущий режим (используют плееры).

Comment: В X (Unix) есть XScreenSaverQueryInfo функция, которая программами гашения экрана может использоваться — [пример на Питоне](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31076523/4279).

Answer (score 3):

Судя по всему в Windows для этого существует функция [`GetLastInputInfo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646302(v=vs.85).aspx). Как следует из описания:

> Retrieves the time of the last input event.

Получает время последнего события ввода.

Answer (score 1):

Делал подобную проверку, и реализовал следующим образом, раз в секунду проверял координаты мышки и если они не совпадали с предыдущими, то значит пользователь проявил активность GetCursorPos(), дальше проверял не нажимались ли клавишы  GetAsyncKeyState(), потом записывал в БД и смотрел график активности.